# How can I solve $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln\left(\sinh x \right) \cdot \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)$?

Tags: limits, analysis

I have to calculate limit:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(\sinh x\right)^{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}$$

I think I can transform it to:
$$e^{\lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln\left(\sinh x \right) \cdot \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

But what to do now? I'm hopeless by limit:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln\left(\sinh x \right) \cdot \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Thank you for any ideas how to solve this limit.

By the way using L'Hopital's rule is restricted for me in this example so I would like to find solution without need of it.

I've already tried rewriting $\sinh x$ to exponential form but I think I can't help me anyhow. Even $\sinh x$ to $-i\sin ix$ identity didn't help me. Any other useful identity I haven't found too.

Thanks to comments I can do another step:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln\left(\sinh x \right) \cdot \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln\left(\sinh x \right) \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \ln\left(\sinh^{\frac{1}{x}} x \right)$$.

Now a problem is to fit $\sinh^{\frac{1}{x}}x$ to $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$. Is it possible when $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches to 0 and $sinh x$ approaches to infinity instead of one?

Context of this question is that I am now preparing for exam and i found this example in  test from previous year. I am studing math first year so I have only few tools awaiable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Hint. $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\arctan(t)/t\to 1$ as $t\to 0$

Comment: Thank you @RobertZ for yout arctan(t)/t hint. I can see it could help me.

Comment: Hint: for large $x$ (small $\frac1x$), $\ln\sinh x\sim x$ while $\arctan\frac1x\sim\frac1x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier if you do, in fact, rewrite $\sinh(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^x - e^{-x}\right)$. Then you end up with $$\ln(e^x - \underbrace{e^{-x}}_{\to 0}) \arctan \frac{1}{x} - \underbrace{\ln 2 \arctan \frac{1}{x}}_{\to 0}$$
where you can justify the $e^{-x}$ term going to $0$ by noting on the one hand that $$\ln(e^x - e^{-x}) \arctan \frac{1}{x} \le \ln(e^x) \arctan \frac{1}{x}$$ and on the other hand that $$\ln(e^x - e^{-x}) \arctan \frac{1}{x} \ge \ln \left(\frac{e^x}{2}\right) \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \ln(e^x)\arctan\frac{1}{x}-\underbrace{\ln(2) \arctan\frac{1}{x}}_{\to 0}$$ for large $x$. (This is not entirely obvious and you do need to justify it.)

So in the limit this is $$\ln(e^x) \arctan \frac{1}{x} = x \arctan \frac{1}{x}$$

Now substitute $h = \frac{1}{x}$: this is $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\arctan h - \arctan 0}{h} \underbrace{=}_{\mathrm{by\ definition}} \arctan'(0) = 1$$ (formally, this is by the inverse function theorem).

Comment: This solution is really clever, simple and clear. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

By asymptotics expansions:
$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\,\sim\,\,\frac{1}{x}$$
for $x\to+\infty$. Also, we have that:
$$\ln(\sinh(x))=\ln\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\right)\,\sim\, \ln(e^x)-\ln(2)=x-\ln(2)$$
So:
$$\ln(\sinh(x))\cdot\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\sim\,\frac{x-\ln(2)}{x}\to 1$$
Thus:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln(\sinh(x))^{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{\ln\left(\sinh x \right) \cdot \arctan \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)}\,=\,\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{\frac{x-\ln(2)}{x}}=1$$

Comment: In the last line, it is better not to mix $\sim$ with limits :). Ciao